# What is the correct format for blogger import xml file?

Tags: blogger

Based on this document, 
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#ExportFormat , I created a text file with contents below, and try to import it into my existing blogger blog. The import process hangs on "importing blog posts" step, and posts do not get created. Is there something wrong with my file format?

```
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
  <title type='text'>Marriage!</title>
  <content type='xhtml'>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <p>Mr. Darcy has <em>proposed marriage</em> to me!</p>
      <p>He is the last man on earth I would ever desire to marry.</p>
      <p>Whatever shall I do?</p>
    </div>
  </content>
  <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="marriage" />
  <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="Mr. Darcy" />
</entry>
```

Comment: This is somewhat a question that involves web development.

Comment: This seems on-topic to me. It's about importing data into Blogger, which is certainly something we cover here.

Comment: right, I am not really writing any code for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this format:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<ns0:feed xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"> 
    <ns0:generator>Blogger</ns0:generator>
    <ns0:entry> 
        <ns0:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008/kind#post" /> 
        <ns0:category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="CATEGORY A" />
        <ns0:category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="CATEGORY B" />
        <ns0:id>BLOGGER TEST</ns0:id> 
        <ns0:content type="html">
            <p>Mr. Darcy has <em>proposed marriage</em> to me!</p>
            <p>He is the last man on earth I would ever desire to marry.</p>
            <p>Whatever shall I do?</p>
        </ns0:content> 
        <ns0:published>2016-04-28T03:22:00.001-05:00</ns0:published> 
        <ns0:title type="html">BLOGGER TITLE</ns0:title> 
    </ns0:entry>
</ns0:feed>
```