# Need format for blogger import of xml file

Tags: blogger, import

In the long-archived topic [What is the correct format for blogger import xml file?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79185/what-is-the-correct-format-for-blogger-import-xml-file), there is a suggested solution, but if it worked when posted in 2016 it no longer does now.

I tried to use the code supplied there, and the import just hangs.

I tried to compare that code with what's in a fresh backup/export from an existing blogger site, and there's just too much css and other material that I don't want to drag along.

Comment: Welcome. Please follow the [tour] (so you will be rewarded with a nice badge). If you don't mind also read [ask]. Anyway, it's very refreshing found a post of a new contributor that shared their search/research efforts.Thank you! (I'm sorry for not providing an answer, I very rarely use Blogger).